# Mongoose validator throws error on update while my condition is true

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that contains Date fields, I need to compare them with each other before saving the document or updating it. It's working fine on creating document, but when I'm trynna to update a document, it throws an error while my conditions are true
This is my code:

```
  const match = await matchModel.findById(req.params.id);

  match.startBuyDate = req.body.startBuyDate || match.startBuyDate;
  match.matchDate = req.body.matchDate || match.matchDate;
  match.visibleDate = req.body.visibleDate || match.visibleDate;
  match.endBuyDate = req.body.endBuyDate || match.endBuyDate;
await matchModel.findByIdAndUpdate(match.id, match, {
    runValidators: true,
  });
```

and these are my custom validators, all of them are returning false

```
//match date could not be lower than current date
  matchDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "a match must have date"],
    validate: {
      validator: function (value) {
        return new Date() < value;
      },
      message:
        "you cant sell tickets for a match in the past! time travel machine has not been invented yet",
    },
  },
  //this field specifies the time that users can see match info on website
  visibleDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "a match must have a visible date"],
    //visible date must be lower than start buy date
    validate: {
      validator: function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        return value < this.startBuyDate;
      },
      message: "visible date must be lower than start buy date",
    },
  },
  //buying tickets for this match will be start from this date
  startBuyDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "a match must have a start buy date"],
    //start buy date must be lower than both end buy date and match date
    validate: {
      validator: function (value) {
        return value < this.endBuyDate && value < this.matchDate;
      },
      message: "startBuyDate must be lower than both endBuyDate and matchDate",
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a mongo object why do you create another

```
  const match = await matchModel.findById(req.params.id);

  match.startBuyDate = req.body.startBuyDate || match.startBuyDate;
  match.matchDate = req.body.matchDate || match.matchDate;
  match.visibleDate = req.body.visibleDate || match.visibleDate;
  match.endBuyDate = req.body.endBuyDate || match.endBuyDate;

await match.save();
```

But I mean if you still want to do your three requests to db instead of two, you need to pass only the fields that are going to be updated, them four dates and pass this params as well

await matchModel.findByIdAndUpdate(match.id, PassFieldsThatWhereUpdated, {
runValidators: true,
new: true,
upsert: true
});